# How to say you taught/educated someone from a different field in your resume?

Tags: resume, computer-science

A friend who studied Computer Science is writing his resume for a new job position.  On his previous work, he worked in a project that included engineers and scientists from different fields. He had to explain (and pretty much teach) to scientists from other backgrounds about software, programming, and other computer-related things.

What would be the best way to write this on a resume?

Comment: he taught a course? Or just explained a few specific things related to a project?

Comment: @Kilisi
Didn't taught a course. Simply explained specific things related to computers and software so the other scientists could understand. Most of it he told me was explaining how to use a new tool he created that automated part of the work scientists were doing manually. Scientists also needed to understand how the program worked internally, so they could feed it data in a proper format.

Comment: Will this skill be relevant in the position he's applying to? If it's a position that doesn't require relaying technical knowledge to stakeholders or educating junior colleagues maybe it's not worth including on his resume.

Comment: @Kilisi
"End user training" might be a good way to explain it. Thank you.

Comment: @Peter
He will have to work with different types of engineers (and most likely report to higher-ups with no technical background), so it might be a good idea to add it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Trained cross-functional team on computer science topics and product use"

Two job req. buzzwords: train and cross-functional team.

Comment: This one sounds good. Short and buzzword worthy.

Answer (score 1):

I would keep it simple without trying to make it sound like more than it was.

Something like created automation tool for XYZ and composed and implemented the procedures and end user training.

This might be dependent on locale, because that's the normal terminology here, the buzzwords in other answers are unknown to me and sound like pretentious sales spiel but may be applicable elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

"Translated technical concepts to non-technical cross-functional team."

I would recommend your friend keep in concise bullet point. It's important to highlight the ability to translate technical concepts to a non-technical audience and work with a cross-functional (diverse roles) team. I wouldn't use the word teach or train unless your friend actually taught a class on the topic.

Answer (score -3):

Quite honestly now ... why not just say it on the resume ... *exactly as you just did?*

Or: "howzabout we now flip the presentation to the opposite corner?" Who, exactly, were the students' "other backgrounds," and exactly what did he teach them, and how did they benefit from his particular skills in doing so?

*"The ability to* ***teach(!)"*** is a skill that many people do not possess.  Therefore: if you have demonstrated it, *showcase* it!

Comment: I honestly don't understand your answer, sorry. Re-read the question please, it's not about a teaching position nor students.